# Visual Studio Serial input from Arduino

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

this is the updated version of the code does this add up with all the edits you made? I think it's mostly accurate but you can also try with visual studio, if you already did is it working on yours?

```
    namespace Lexis
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                serialPort1.Open();
                string lastLine = string.Empty;
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string tailValue = lastLine;
                        lastLine = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        string line = lastLine;
                        label1.BeginInvoke(new Action
                                               (() =>
                                               {
                                                   label1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || string.Equals(tailValue, line)
                                                                  ? label1.Text
                                                                  : $"{line}{Environment.NewLine}{label1.Text}";
                                               }
                                               ));

                        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();







                    }
                });


            }
            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: serialPort1.ReadLine(); why you use it for getting last line?

 `string lastLine = serialPort1.ReadLine(); label1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastLine) ? label1.Text  : $"{lastLine}{Environment.NewLine}{label1.Text}";`

Comment: @AdemCatamak thank you so much, I just have one more question, I need it to update every second but a while loop doesn't seem to work, is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your golden solution but I hope this gives you a lead.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    serialPort1.Open();

    string currentLine = string.Empty;
    object mylock = new object();
    Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     lock (mylock)
                     {
                         string previousLine = currentLine;
                         currentLine = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                         string line = currentLine;
                         label1.BeginInvoke(new Action
                                                (() =>
                                                 {
                                                     label1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || string.Equals(previousLine, line)
                                                                       ? label1.Text
                                                                       : $"{line}{Environment.NewLine}{label1.Text}";
                                                 }
                                                ));

                         Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();
                     }
                 }
             });
}
```

Comment: it updates it in a weird way, I linked an image of what it's doing at the very top

Comment: Also I had to change  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); to Task.Delay(10).Wait(); because the first one gave me an error

Comment: I edit my answer a little bit. `serialPort1.ReadLine();` return last line for you, after than if you call ReadLine again it give you the same value again. Hence, I add `string.Equals(tailValue, line)` condition.

Comment: ): It still seems to be acting weird, I updated the image at the top

Comment: Can you modified `Task.Delay(10).Wait();`  to `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();` or `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();`

10 means 10 milliseconds. Probably threads try to update label content the same time. This may leads to absurd content like screenshot

Comment: I was using Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); and I had the same results

Comment: I edit my code. But I do not have opinion about real reason why program result look likes that. I'm guessing in the light of the screenshoots.

Moreover, in past, I could not get satisfactory results with the System.IO.Ports -SerialPort- library. I hope you can reach your goal

Comment: Okay, I updated the original code at the top, does it add up?